# Python - VK API

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Короче, делаю бота для вк.
Именно в api ещё не сильно разобрался, но пытаюсь.
Вообщем, застрял на проблеме с методом likes.add, не могу понять как он работает, при попытке использовать его api выдает ошибку

> line 79, in 
>       vk.method("likes.add", {"type": (str(getlikeaddtype)), "item_id": (int(likesadditem))})
>   TypeError: **call**() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Кто знает как решить?
Вот код:

```
print("What errors can be?:\n 30 - This profile is private.")
    likesadditem = input("Item ID: ")
    getlikeaddtype = input("What type? \npost\ncomment\nphoto\naudio\nvideo\nnote\nmarket\nphoto_comment\nvideo_comment\ntopic_comment\nmarket_comment\n")
    vk.method("likes.add", {"type": (str(getlikeaddtype)), "item_id": (int(likesadditem))})
```

Если в коде есть ошибки, прошу не судить.

Comment: Приведите достаточно полный код, позволяющий воспроизвести проблему

Comment: @andreymal

 if main == "getLikeAdd":
  print("What errors can be?:\n 30 - This profile is private.")
  likesadditem = input("Item ID: ")
  getlikeaddtype = input("What type? \npost\ncomment\nphoto\naudio\nvideo\nnote\nmarket\nphoto_comment\nvideo_comment\ntopic_comment\nmarket_comment\n")
  vk.method("likes.add", {"type": (str(getlikeaddtype)), "item_id": (int(likesadditem))})
  print("Item: " + (likesadditem) + "Succesfully liked.")

Это и есть весь этот метод.

Comment: Всё ещё недостаточно полный. Например, в показанном вами коде не существует никакой переменной main или vk

Comment: @andreymal https://pastebin.com/1XyGYAQj

Comment: Уберите из кода всё, что не относится к описанной проблеме, и поместите оставшееся в текст вопроса

Comment: @andreymal Ну так вот же:
 if main == "getLikeAdd":
        print("What errors can be?:\n 30 - This profile is private.")
        likesadditem = input("Item ID: ")
        getlikeaddtype = input("What type? \npost\ncomment\nphoto\naudio\nvideo\nnote\nmarket\nphoto_comment\nvideo_comment\ntopic_comment\nmarket_comment\n")
        vk.method("likes.add", {"type": (str(getlikeaddtype)), "item_id": (int(likesadditem))})

Что то не так в vk.method, там происходит ошибка.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Fruthy Ну так в этом коде из комментария вы зачем-то убрали переменную vk, которая к проблеме очень даже относится. Вы должны предоставить минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример, иначе вероятность получения ответа будет стремиться к нулю, как и полезность вопроса для базы знаний.

Comment: @TEA Is okay???

Comment: И тем не менее с чего это вдруг вы стали использовать стиль вызова `vk.method("likes.add"` вместо `vk.likes.add(` как в других местах вашего кода? Объекты VkApiMethod не поддерживают такого смешивания.

Comment: @andreymal Пытался попробывать как то исправить проблему.
Тоесть просто пошёл на ютуб и из других уроков взял пример использования.

+ я не знаю как задавать параметры с vk.likes.add()

Comment: Ну так у людей на ютубе объект vk является совершенно другим объектом, естественно бездумное копирование рандомных кусков кода работать не будет.

Comment: «я не знаю как задавать параметры» — как же это вы не знаете, если в случае `vk.wall.post` вы параметры без проблем задаёте?

Comment: @andreymal Ох, уже не помню как это написал. Вообщем, можете написать пример использования likes.add ? Уже 2 часа сижу понять не могу как он должен работать.

Comment: @andreymal По сути, я как то не так указываю параметры, и апи их не видит.

Answer (score 0):

Бот не может ставить лайки по правилам сообщества вк.